# In a matrix does every set of r row vectors need to be linearly independent for rank to be r?

Tags: matrices

Rank of a matrix is the maximum number of linearly independent row vectors , does every set of r row vectors need to be linearly independent or finding only one set of r row vectors which are linearly independent is enough?

Comment: The latter is the correct statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not every set of $r$ vectors will be linearly independent -- this is why it's the *maximum* number of linearly independent rows. Consider the following rank 2 matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.$$
The first two rows are not linearly independent, so the rank is at most 2. The latter two rows are linearly independent, so the rank is indeed 2.